# Pass modelAndView objects after redirect to the receiving controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Post Controller that takes an input form fields and after some calculations and retrieving db values, it redirects to the Get Controller with two Parameters.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/calculate", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String compareClients(@Valid UserInfo calculate, BindingResult bindingResult) {

   /*some calculations*/
    long firstClient=calculate.getFirstId();
    long secondClient=calculate.getSecondId();
    ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("firstInfo",firstInfo);
    modelAndView.addObject("secondInfo",secondInfo);
    modelAndView.addObject("infoId",id);

return "redirect:/user/calculate?firstId=" + firstClient + "&secondId=" + secondClient;
```

I want to pass the firstInfo,secondInfo and infoId to the other controller so that from there I display it on the thymeleaf

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/calculate", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "firstId", "secondId" })
public ModelAndView comparison(@RequestParam(value = "firstId", required = true) String firstId,@RequestParam(value = "secondId", required = true) String secondId) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("firstClient", firstId);
    modelAndView.addObject("secondClient", secondId);
 return modelAndView;
}
```

How do I achieve this ? Please help.
I tried using forward instead of redirect but it takes too long to respond, and it doesn't forward to the Get Controller.
Can't use flashAttributes because I need the info on the Thymeleaf if I refresh the page.
And I can't pass all 5 object through the URL. IT'd be better if those were hidden from it.

Comment: Have you tried parametrizing your methods with the `Model` and adding an attribute?

Comment: 'I need the info on the Thymeleaf if I refresh the page' and 'I can't pass all 5 object through the URL' sound like conflicting goals. You'll have to use a session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have so much idea about `Thymeleaf` but you can pass your desired value to another controller using `RedirectAttributes`. Since your comment want for persist the value upon refresh the page. So I am giving you an example using `SessionAttributes`

```
public class YourInfo{
    private String firstInfo;
    private String secondInfo;

    //setter and getter
}
```

Your controller class add a session attribute annotation

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("myInfo")
```

Now Move to request part.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/calculate", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String compareClients(@Valid UserInfo calculate, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

   /*some calculations*/
    long firstClient=calculate.getFirstId();
    long secondClient=calculate.getSecondId();
    ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("firstInfo",firstClient);
    modelAndView.addObject("secondInfo",secondClient);
    modelAndView.addObject("infoId",id);
    if(!model.containsAttribute("myInfo")){
        YourInfo yourInfo = new YourInfo();
        yourInfo.setFirstInfo(String.valueOf(firstClient));
        yourInfo.setSecondInfo(String.valueOf(secondClient));
        model.addAttribute("myInfo",yourInfo);
    }

    return "redirect:/user/calculate";
}
```

And your get controller (Assuming that your firstInfo and secondInfo will be string)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/calculate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView comparison(@ModelAttribute("myInfo") YourInfo yourInfo) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("firstClient", yourInfo.getFirstInfo());
    modelAndView.addObject("secondClient", yourInfo.getSecondInfo());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But with addFlashAttribute I only get the values once, for one use. After a refresh they're deleted.
And I need them for further

Comment: @EmmA, If you need it for refresh, then you should use spring `SessionAttributes`.

Comment: Thank you, but that's what I'm not sure how to use. Since it's multiple attributes.
I annotate the Controller class like this 
`@SessionAttributes(value= {"firstInfo","secondInfo","infoId"})`

And then on the GetController I have
`@ModelAttribute("firstInfo") String firstInfo,@ModelAttribute("secondInfo") String secondInfo,@ModelAttribute("infoId") String infoId` as parameters
And the Post controller has a modelAndView.addObject() where it adds those.
But the session doesn't read those values. Am I missing something ?
Thank you!